# How to change video to fullscreen and windowed in console

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How to change video to fullscreen and windowed in console? This is because Valve doesn't fix the bug of showing scoreboard when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so the quick way would be to make this change as quick as possible.

Answer (score 15):

`mat_setvideomode 1920 1080 0` // 1080p Fullscreen

`mat_setvideomode 1920 1080 1` // 1080p Window Mode

You can use these to change to windowed/full-screen (specify your own resolution if it's not 1080p).

Then you can bind a key to switch between fullscreen and windowed like this:

`bind "F3" "toggle mat_setvideomode 1920 1080 0 1"`

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding this answer because I am unable to comment:

I was unable to switch between fullscreen and windowed by using the toggle command. If you want to toggle full screen on and off with a button, I found these commands to work:

```
alias turnOnFullscreen "bind F11 turnOffFullscreen;mat_setvideomode 1920 1080 0"
alias turnOffFullscreen "bind F11 turnOnFullscreen;mat_setvideomode 1920 1080 1"
bind F11 turnOffFullscreen
```

And then you can of course change the button from F11 to something else and change your resolution from 1920x1080 if you want a different resolution :)